# Redirect using apache conf file 404 error

Tags: apache, redirect

I have a beta wordpress site (beta.domain.co.uk) I would like to redirect to (domain.co.uk).

I have a `.conf` file for each site pointing to its folder with the wordpress files.

I have tried just renaming the folders but I get a 404 error.

How can I point the beta site to my main site?

main site conf :

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName www.domain.co.uk
       DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.co.uk
       <Directory />
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
       </Directory>
       <Directory /var/www/domain.co.uk/>
          Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride None
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
       </Directory>
       ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName domain.co.uk
      RewriteEngine on
      RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
    </VirtualHost>
```

beta site conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName beta.domain.co.uk
   DocumentRoot /var/www/beta.domain.co.uk
   <Directory />
      Options FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
   </Directory>
   <Directory /var/www/beta.domain.co.uk/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
   </Directory>
   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following rewrite rules, make sure you put it inside the beta site conf, inside virtualhost.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^beta\.domain\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```